# How to mark day in CalendarView in my Android application?

Tags: java, android

I have been developing the Android application and I use CalendarView in it. I have seen marked days (black triangles) in standart Android application. How can I do the same in my application?

Comment: CalendarView extends View. You could use an Adapter and override it's method getView